# How to handle SSL Error with Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to send request to one PDF link.

```
link = "https://publicationtc.fr.ch/tribunavtplus/ServletDownload/605_2022_1_a514394f9f18429995d4cd5c64fbc6de.pdf?path=89599fc4428b36e430bdf3f8a743749b72d66ad9c60b26ec73eca465d87e271c4ac6ee641573804bc4054a0a0676852bfe9af512f2004244ba03d7aac8659e1637de9fb6178bb32ca6bb9c945937d5eb&pathIsEncrypted=1&dossiernummer=605_2022_1"
```

I have tried:

```
response = requests.get(link, verify = True)
```

and

```
response = requests.get(link, verify = False)
```

But I always get the same error:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='publicationtc.fr.ch', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /tribunavtplus/ServletDownload/605_2022_1_a514394f9f18429995d4cd5c64fbc6de.pdf?path=89599fc4428b36e430bdf3f8a743749b72d66ad9c60b26ec73eca465d87e271c4ac6ee641573804bc4054a0a0676852bfe9af512f2004244ba03d7aac8659e1637de9fb6178bb32ca6bb9c945937d5eb&pathIsEncrypted=1&dossiernummer=605_2022_1 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

The website requires you to set a User-Agent as header. With requests you can to that like this:

```
link = "https://publicationtc.fr.ch/tribunavtplus/ServletDownload/605_2022_1_a514394f9f18429995d4cd5c64fbc6de.pdf?path=89599fc4428b36e430bdf3f8a743749b72d66ad9c60b26ec73eca465d87e271c4ac6ee641573804bc4054a0a0676852bfe9af512f2004244ba03d7aac8659e1637de9fb6178bb32ca6bb9c945937d5eb&pathIsEncrypted=1&dossiernummer=605_2022_1"

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'}
resp = requests.get(link, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

Please also note that you are loading a .pdf-file, so you can use `.content` instead of `.text` like this to save the file.

```
with open('example.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(resp.content)
```